# Spring converter priority

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a springboot application with two Converters that can convert from class A to class B.
B is extending A.

When I call the Conversion Service, A is always invoked.

I would like have the Conversion Service to call B over A.
I tried @Order and @Primary but none of that worked.

Is there a way to define a priority?

-- EDIT

I am using Springboot + Mapstruct + https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-spring-extensions

If I take for a example: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-spring-extensions/tree/main/examples/custom-conversion-service-bean/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/extensions/spring/example/custombean

which generates `CarMapperImpl` (which implements `Converter`) and I extend it like this:

```java
@Component
public class CarMapperImplExtended extends CarMapperImpl {

public CarMapperImplExtended(ConversionServiceAdapter conversionServiceAdapter) {
        super(conversionServiceAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public CarDto convert(Car car) {
        CarDto carDto = super.convert(car);
        // do something special with it
        return carDto;
    }
}
```

The code is generated, that's why I am gonna end up with two beans implementing `Converter<Car, CarDto>`.
Ideally, I would not have `CarMapperImpl` - true - but I could not find another way to use mapstruct-extension and override convert or remove `@Component` from the generated code.

Finally, I found a workaround: if there are two converters implementing `Converter<A,B>` the `ConversionService` is going to use the one added *last*.

If `CarMapperImplA` and `CarMapperImplB` exist, `CarMapperImplB` will be used.

Comment: Can you share your implementation?

Comment: _Normally_, you would want to prevent a bean of `A` from being registered in the context.

Comment: If the problem is the order of dependency injection, @Qualifer may help.

Comment: I tried @Primary, but that does not help. I have to look into the spring code, but it looks like the converter loaded last replaces the existing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using `@DecoratedWith` with spring component model as explained here:

https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappers-using-decorators